# Get only 20 or less images from IP camera and then only nulls

Tags: c#, image, camera, ip, httpwebresponse

Iam trying to write a code, which will connect to IP camera and get a jpeg image from it. It goes like this:

```
            HttpWebRequest request;                                
            CookieContainer cookies= new CookieContainer();

            //First, I log to IP camera on adress http://192.168.0.2
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(sanyoUrls[0]));
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;

            // then I try to get the IP camera jpeg image from adress http://192.168.0.2/liveimg.cgi        
            cookies = request.CookieContainer;
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(sanyoUrls[1]));
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                using (Stream strImg = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    MemoryStream memStr = new MemoryStream();
                    strImg.CopyTo(memStr);

                    if (response.ContentType == "application/xml")
                    {
                        // write message to GUI
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(memStr);
                            PBcameraImage.Image = bmp;                      
                            // write OK to file
                        }
                        catch (ArgumentException ex)
                        {
                            // write NULL to file
                        }

                    }
                }
                response.Close();
            }
```

This code is executed with specified period (I tried 40 ms up to 1 seconds). And the log in the file looks usually like this:
First is NULL, then 20 times OK, and after it are in the file only NULLs with some exception of single OK line after long time. So I get only 20 pictures from IP camera. Any advices? Thank you.

Cheers,
Ondrej

Comment: Idea: Maybe the software that is streaming the image is demo?

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I solved the problem by adding the line: request.Headers.Add("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "IE").

Comment: Which software are you using?